# Сортировка сложного многомерного массива с помощью php

Tags: массивы, сортировка, php7

Есть массив вида:

```
  [2]=>
  array(10) {
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(12) "Ширина обода"
    ["INPUT"]=>
    string(735) ""
    ["INPUT_NAME"]=>
    string(27) "arrFilter_pf[SHIRINA_OBODA]"
    ["INPUT_VALUE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["~INPUT_VALUE"]=>
    NULL
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(6) "SELECT"
    ["INPUT_NAMES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["INPUT_VALUES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["~INPUT_VALUES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["LIST"]=>
    array(21) {
      [""]=>
      string(5) "(все)"
      [5776]=>
      string(1) "4"
      [967]=>
      string(1) "5"
      [2573]=>
      string(3) "5.5"
      [2574]=>
      string(1) "6"
      [2582]=>
      string(1) "7"
      [2583]=>
      string(3) "6.5"
      [5635]=>
      string(1) "8"
      [5679]=>
      string(3) "7.5"
      [5680]=>
      string(3) "8.5"
      [5711]=>
      string(1) "9"
      [5681]=>
      string(3) "9.5"
      [5712]=>
      string(2) "10"
      [5713]=>
      string(4) "10.5"
      [5714]=>
      string(2) "11"
      [5738]=>
      string(3) "4.5"
      [5790]=>
      string(5) "11.75"
      [5715]=>
      string(4) "11.5"
      [5791]=>
      string(4) "6.75"
      [5792]=>
      string(4) "8.25"
      [5793]=>
      string(4) "5.25"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(10) {
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(13) "Диаметр диска"
    ["INPUT"]=>
    string(537) ""
    ["INPUT_NAME"]=>
    string(27) "arrFilter_pf[DIAMETR_OBODA]"
    ["INPUT_VALUE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["~INPUT_VALUE"]=>
    NULL
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(6) "SELECT"
    ["INPUT_NAMES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["INPUT_VALUES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["~INPUT_VALUES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["LIST"]=>
    array(15) {
      [""]=>
      string(5) "(все)"
      [2590]=>
      string(2) "15"
      [1125]=>
      string(2) "13"
      [2579]=>
      string(2) "14"
      [2591]=>
      string(2) "16"
      [5399]=>
      string(2) "18"
      [5645]=>
      string(2) "17"
      [5646]=>
      string(2) "12"
      [5647]=>
      string(2) "19"
      [5648]=>
      string(2) "20"
      [5649]=>
      string(2) "21"
      [5650]=>
      string(2) "22"
      [5781]=>
      string(4) "17.5"
      [5651]=>
      string(4) "22.5"
      [5782]=>
      string(4) "19.5"
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(10) {
    ["NAME"]=>
    string(21) "Посадочные отверствия"
    ["INPUT"]=>
    string(980) ""
    ["INPUT_NAME"]=>
    string(37) "arrFilter_pf[POSADOCHNYE_OTVERSTVIYA]"
    ["INPUT_VALUE"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["~INPUT_VALUE"]=>
    NULL
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(6) "SELECT"
    ["INPUT_NAMES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["INPUT_VALUES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["~INPUT_VALUES"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["LIST"]=>
    array(26) {
      [""]=>
      string(5) "(все)"
      [2222]=>
      string(7) "4*114.3"
      [2575]=>
      string(5) "4*100"
      [1080]=>
      string(4) "4*98"
      [2584]=>
      string(5) "5*105"
      [2567]=>
      string(7) "5*114.3"
      [2585]=>
      string(7) "5*139.7"
      [2586]=>
      string(5) "5*100"
      [2595]=>
      string(5) "5*115"
      [2596]=>
      string(5) "5*108"
      [5652]=>
      string(5) "5*112"
      [5653]=>
      string(5) "5*130"
      [5654]=>
      string(5) "5*150"
      [5655]=>
      string(7) "6*139.7"
      [5656]=>
      string(5) "5*120"
      [5657]=>
      string(5) "5*105"
      [5721]=>
      string(5) "5*110"
      [5695]=>
      string(4) "63.3"
      [5722]=>
      string(5) "4*108"
      [5752]=>
      string(5) "5*160"
      [5730]=>
      string(11) "5*100/114.3"
      [5723]=>
      string(5) "6*130"
      [5753]=>
      string(5) "6*170"
      [5754]=>
      string(4) "3*98"
      [5755]=>
      string(5) "6*205"
      [5783]=>
      string(6) "10*335"
    }
```

Можно как-то отсортировать все LIST по value (от меньшего к большему) не трогая key ???

Answer (score 0):

```
function list_up($a, $b) {
    if ($a['LIST'] === $b['LIST']) return 0;
    return $a['LIST'] < $b['LIST'] ? 1 : -1;
}
function list_down($a, $b) {
    if ($a['LIST'] === $b['LIST']) return 0;
    return $a['LIST'] > $b['LIST'] ? 1 : -1;
}

uasort($masiv, 'list_up');
```

> Вставите правильные ключи до ключа LIST

Comment: function list_up($a, $b) {
    if ($a[2]['LIST'] === $b[2]['LIST']) return 0;
    return $a[2]['LIST'] < $b[2]['LIST'] ? 1 : -1;
}
function list_down($a, $b) {
    if ($a[2]['LIST'] === $b[2]['LIST']) return 0;
    return $a[2]['LIST'] > $b[2]['LIST'] ? 1 : -1;
}

uasort($masiv, 'list_up');     В таком виде не сортирует.

Comment: Предлагаю пересмотреть структуру массива , внутри лист добавлять массивы такого вида $arr[2]['LIST'][] = array('id'=>$id, 'value'=>$value);

тогда сортировка упростится по ключам $arr[2]['LIST']['value'];
в текущем положение мне не ясно как указать значение для сортировки  не зная его ключа. Упустил этот момент. Для правельной сортировки мы должны указать правильный путь до значения .

Comment: Теоретически можно что то придумать, циклом например, но будет жрать много ОЗУ